# La voix passive

Tags: grammaire, traduction, passif

The English Passive may often be rendered by the French Passive. However, the French Passive is less frequently employed than the English and various constructions are commonly used instead (on+active verb, reflexive verb, etc.).
So for

> Farsi is spoken in Iran.

the French translation

> Le farsi est parlé en Iran.

would sound, I guess, awkward to the natifs and one of the following would be preferred:

> On parle farsi en Iran; Le farsi se parle en Iran.

1. I am wondering why French Passive is not so common as the English one.
2. When is the French Passive inappropriate and
3. when is its usage unavoidable?

---

La voix passive anglaise peut souvent être rendue par la voix passive française. Cependant, la voix passive française est moins fréquemment employée que l'anglaise et diverses constructions sont communément employées à sa place (on + verbe actif, verbe réfléchi, etc.).
Donc pour

> Le farsi est parlé en Iran.

la traduction

> Le farsi est parlé en Iran.

semblerait, je suppose, gênante et on préfère l'une des formulations suivantes :

> On parle farsi en Iran. Le farsi se parle en Iran.

1. Pourquoi la voix passive n'est-elle pas si commune en français ?
2. Quand la voix passive est-elle complètement inappropriée
3. Quand son utilisation est-elle inévitable?

Comment: La forme passive "sonne" lourdement à l'oreille. Il est recommandé tant que possible de l'éviter car elle peut être employé souvent et un texte qui serait simple à l'actif devient lourd.

Comment: passive form "sounds" badly to french hears. It's recommanded to avoid it as mush as possible because if used too often it could turn any text into a complex ugly sauce.

Comment: "pourquoi la voix passive n'est pas si commune en français" : Sans doute justement parce qu'il y a d'autres moyens, notamment la forme impersonnelle "on" que vous évoquez.

Comment: The observations are correct. The question of "why" is a good one and the answer can't just be "because there are other ways". Requires a good linguistic look at French's typology to understand why those other ways are preferable. Sadly syntax was never my strongest branch.

Comment: On ne dit pas « Le farsi se parle en Iran ». D'autre part « Le farsi est parlé en Iran » est la réponse naturelle à « Où est parlé le Farsi ? » et celà n'a absolument rien de gênant. C'est une information sur la langue, et pas sur les usages Iraniens. Les deux phrases s'utilisent pour des besoins différents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***La façon de concevoir la réalité:**
les Anglo-Saxons n’aiment pas « formuler tout de suite un jugement ou même une opinion ». 
**La voix passive**, qui permet de « constater un phénomène sans l’attribuer à une cause précise ou qui ne mentionne la cause ou l’agent qu’accessoirement », sert très bien ce besoin d’« objectivité anglaise ».

***La grammaire**:
Le pronom indéfini on est souvent traduit par un passif anglais.
**On les a interrogés pendant deux heures. 
They were questioned for two hours.**

L’expression **être en train** de ne peut être suivie d’un infinitif à la voix passive. 
Cependant, en anglais, la forme progressive peut se mettre au passif.
**On est en train de réparer cette machine. 
This machine is being repaired.
On était en train d’asphalter cette route. 
This road was being paved.**

Le *verbe faire suivi d’un infinitif* doit être à la voix active en français.
**On m’a fait travailler. I was made to work.
On le lui a fait recommencer. He was made to do it again.**

Les *verbes de perception voir et entendre*, suivis d’un autre verbe, doivent être mis à la voix active en français.
**On l’a vu manger la pomme. He was seen eating the apple.
On l’a entendue chanter. She was heard singing.**

**Voix passive en français:**

*Certains verbes impersonnels* peuvent aussi s’employer au passif.
**Il en sera parlé plus tard.
Il est rappelé au public que…**

Hope it's not confusing...

Comment: Quel est le problème avec « Cette route était en train d'être asphaltée » ? D'autre part tu confonds voix passive et tournures impersonelles et pronoms indéfinis. Il faut aussi faire attention à ne pas être trop catégorique: « Il a été vu » et « Elle a été entendue » existent, même si ça ne s'emploie pas (toujours) dans les mêmes circonstances que la tournure anglaise.

Comment: What is the link between *il en sera parlé* and impersonal verbs? And what about middle passives that are not available in English?