# Forme passive de cette phrase

Tags: grammaire, passif

Comment transformer la phrase suivante à la voix passive :

> Son indifférence m'ayant désespérée, j'avais décidé de rompre.

Je dirais :

> Ayant été désespérée par son indifférence, j'avais décidé de rompre.

Mais je ne sais pas si c'est correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Son indifférence m'ayant désespérée, j'avais décidé de rompre.
>
> Ayant été désespérée par son indifférence, j'avais décidé de rompre.

La phrase est bien correcte. See

[La voix passive](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30147/la-voix-passive/30195#30195)

J'aurais du préciser que je ne suis pas un locuteur natif du français.

Merci @jlliagre qui note en commentaire que la seconde variante, qui est allégée du superflu, est à préférer :

> Désespérée par son indifférence, j'avais décidé de rompre.

et @Stephane Gimenez

*« On préfère éviter la voie passive ». Certainement pas dans le cas en question. C'est vraiment une remarque trompeuse, la voie passive est utile dans beaucoup de cas, il n'y a aucune raison de « l'éviter ». Si c'est un conseil pour les anglophones qui seraient tentés de calquer la syntaxe anglaise, en effet, il faut faire attention.*

Comment: Moi, je préfère la seconde, allégée du superflu: *Désespérée par son indifférence, j'avais décidé de rompre.*

Comment: @jlliagre Commentaire rajouté à la réponse rajoutée. Merci !

Comment: *"Je ne suis pas un locuteur natif*" ! ... *" ἀλλ᾽ εἴπερ ἐστι μὴ χελιδόνος δίκην
ἀγνῶτα φωνὴν βάρβαρον κεκτημένη"* ... J'espère que tu me pardonneras, you made my day! ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt http://www.greek-language.gr/digitalResources/ancient_greek/library/browse.html?text_id=129&page=27

Comment: « On préfère éviter la voie passive ».  Certainement pas dans le cas en question. C'est vraiment une remarque trompeuse, la voie passive est utile dans beaucoup de cas, il n'y a aucune raison de « l'éviter ». Si c'est un conseil pour les anglophones qui seraient tentés de calquer la syntaxe anglaise, en effet, il faut faire attention. « Comme déjà répondu » est justement  un usage qui n'est pas français !

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est noté ; réponse éditée. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

La transformation est correcte !